# Defining a function within a loop using loadstring with Lua 5.1

Tags: lua

I'm currently trying to define a function using a combination of concatenation, loadstring, and a for loop.

This is the kind of thing I have currently:

```
> for f=1,8 do
loadstring("function f" .. f .. " () print('" .. f .. "') end")
end
> f1()
stdin:1: attempt to call global 'f1' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

The function evaluates a set of chunks in the form of: 'function f () print() end'. However, as you can see, it doesn't seem to save the function into the variables f1-f8 correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loadstring() function returns a function that, when called, executes the code given as an argument.  It doesn't actually call the function or run the code.  Try the following:

```
for f=1,8 do
loadstring("function f" .. f .. " () print('" .. f .. "') end")()
end
```

The added parenthesis calls the function that has just been created by loadstring(), creating your numbered functions.

Comment: You should assert that `loadstring` returned a valid chunk first. That way, you can get compiler errors in case something breaks.

Comment: @Nicol In general, yes you should.  However my read is that this piece of code is more of an academic exercise than a useful component of a robust application.

Comment: I see. In the documentation it just said 'loads a chunk using the string', which I just interpreted to mean that it ran the code in the string. I didn't read the part underneath it which said how to run the code.    

And yes, it is more of an academic exercise. What I want to actually do is slightly more complex, but I can figure that part out on my own. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The same thing can be accomplished with

```
for f=1,8 do
   _G["f"..f]=function () print(f) end
end
```

Comment: Woah, is _G like a global table that holds all the global variables?

Comment: Yes, `_G` contains the table that holds all the global variables but is not at all a special variable.